# Overflow and underflow of a probability value

Tags: probability, exponential-function, computational-mathematics, floating-point

I am evaluating the probability that the minimum of a process is a above a a barrier $\log(H)$. The probability is given by $$P_i=1-\exp\left(-2\frac{(\log(H)-x)(\log(H)-x_b)}{\tau\sigma^2}\right).$$ So $x,x_b$ are the two end point value for the interval of length $\tau$.

The problem is that $P_i$ may negative during a simulation in which $x,x_b,\tau$ change which doesn't make sense. How can this calculated to avoid this problem?

Comment: What are you using for computing ? C++ code, Fortran, Mathematica ???

Comment: What is the actual process you are simulating? If you are not already doing so, Monte Carlo methods could help you avoid negative answers and get you a good answer.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, I am using matlab

Comment: @Eupraxis1981, I am simulating a jump diffusion process, $P_i$ is the probability that the process (which is a pure diffusion between jumps) is above the barrier $\log(H)$ between jumps.

Comment: @Eupraxis1981, let me add that it is a Monte carlo simulation

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the exponential can become greater than $1$, which happens when the argument is greater than $0$.  As long as both $x, x_b \gt \log H$ you don't have a problem.  The problem is when one of them is less than $\log H$, which shouldn't happen if that is a barrier.  Maybe it is roundoff error in assessing the barrier?